# QT FileDialog and QT Scene freeze program

Tags: c++, qt

I have a big issue with executing QFileDialog. In my program I have nodes connected with links that are drawn on scene. I read specific node data from file (doesn't matter atm) and save to file. Sometimes, when I open the file and draw graph (I'm using boost graph to position nodes) and I open dialog file second time it works, but usually it just opens part of FileDialog (white box, with no buttons) and freeze. When I remove some items from scene (it usually contains ~130 Nodes and ~300 links) it works perfectly. Moreover, when I set position of all nodes to some big value (moving them outside of my screen) or even set them invisible it works too. It seems to have problem with QFileDialog executing when scene contains too many objects that are aviable too see on the scene. Has anyone had simillar problem or know how to solve that issue? If u need more information feel free to ask. Thanks for every ideas.

Comment: is your data heavy enough to grab lots of memory? may be graphic memory touched it limits and denied to do more work.

Comment: What is the "scene"? A QGraphicsView/Scene? And what are the nodes and links exactly?